# Jetpack compose check if a function has been run in preview mode

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Is this possible to check if a function has been run in preview mode in Jetpack compose? I have a function that returns a proper string to use in the app but this function uses some objects which disable preview mode for `@Composable` components. What I could do is to pass `val isPreview: Boolean = false` flag to every component and then run a simplified function if the flag is `true` but this adds some boilerplate code to every composable.

Comment: Based on the answers posted here, I created an [optimized version](https://gist.github.com/crizzis/fe2697e314835d1cfb71a9e11f6af3c8) that works for both static and interactive mode preview. Not posting it here as an answer, since it's only an expansion on other people's ideas

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I usually do this by calling `LocalInspectionMode.current` to know if I'm in preview mode. It returns `true` if in preview mode.

Here's what the documentation says about [`LocalInspectionMode`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/platform/package-summary#LocalInspectionMode()):

> Inspectable mode CompositionLocal. True if the composition is composed inside an Inspectable component.

Comment: This article provides working example of how to use it (works in Jan 2023) https://developermemos.com/posts/checking-composable-render-preview

You should pass it to the function parameters. It doesn't compile if you just try to use it inside the composable function code
`@Composable fun ExampleView( isPreview: Boolean = LocalInspectionMode.current)`

Answer (score 3):

They don't (as of Jan 2022) host the @Preview Jetpack Compose code in a your MainActivity when Preview-ing items in Android Studio.

This means you can walk up the context.baseContext tree to determine if you're in your app's MainActivity class or another app's top-level activity class. My top-level activity is called MainActivity, so:

```
fun Context.findMainActivityOrNull(): MainActivity?{
  var context = this
  while (context is ContextWrapper) {
    if (context is MainActivity) return context
    context = context.baseContext
  }
  return null
}
```

This makes it so I can avoid setting the status bar color when in preview, that way it doesn't crash the preview trying to do that.

You call the above function like this:

```
context.findMainActivityOrNull() //when in a non-@Composable area
```

If you're in a @Composable function, then you should be able to go:

```
LocalContext.current.findMainActivityOrNull()
```

You can get fancy and wrap the misbehaving class up in an adapter to be neat and tidy about it, or just check if the result of the above is null when working around a few issues.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to accepted action, in case you want to render Composable in preview mode in Paparazzi screenshot test - [here](https://github.com/cashapp/paparazzi#localinspectionmode) is official workaround, which is to wrap Composable in `CompositionLocalProvider`:

```
 @Test
  fun inspectionModeView() {
    paparazzi.snapshot(
      CompositionLocalProvider(LocalInspectionMode provides true) {
        YourComposable()
      }
    )
  }
```

Answer (score -3):

This will violate the functional paradigm of a composable function. It should be **stateless** and will not care if its running in preview mode or in an actual app or else, you will encounter unexpected bugs in the future when the app gets very large to manage.

You should try to refactor or restructure your composable so that it will only depend on the string directly as a parameter. The preview mode can send a hardcoded string for this composable but for your actual app, you can call that function that returns the proper string (which uses some objects).

More about "Thinking in Compose" [here](https://www.example.com/)

Comment: I know that I can use String function parameters but what happens when my view has to display 10 strings and all strings will always be the same and control only has a sense with these particular strings. Now every time I have to pass 10 strings to this composable

Comment: "will not care if its running in preview mode" - Yes, ideally, but sometimes in the real world there are genuine practical reasons.  For example: the Coil SVG library exhibiting a bug that crashes Previews but works at Runtime, and you just want to suppress that part in Previews it so you can continue your work and fix it later.

Comment: The functional paradigm of a composable function is violated by the reality of the differences between the Compose preview window and the Android environment. Most people who are searching for a solution here need to know when they are in a @Preview decorated section to allow us to make them behave *more* alike, by faking items not provided in the Android Studio preview.